# linux shell: How to read command argument from a file?

Tags: linux, pipe, xargs

I have process id in a file "pid"
I'd like to kill it.

Something like:

```
kill -9 <read pid from file>
```

I tried:

```
kill -9 `more pid`
```

but it does not work. I also tried `xargs` but can't get my head around it.

Comment: I think it's the `more` bit that is killing it b/c `more` might be expecting user input.

Comment: http://www.speculation.org/garrick/kill-9.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me summarize all answers

```
kill -9 $(cat pid)
kill -9 `cat pid`
cat pid | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 13):

Does

```
kill -9 $(cat pid)
```

work for you?

Comment: +1. I prefer the $() method over backticks, since you can nest them.

Answer (score 3):

my preference is

```
kill -9 `cat pid`
```

that will work for any command in the backticks.

Answer (score 2):

`kill -9 $(cat pid)`  or `cat pid | xargs kill -9` will both work

Answer (score 2):

You should be starting off gradually and then move up to the heavy stuff to kill the process if it doesn't want to play nicely.

A SIGKILL (-9) signal can't be caught and that will mean that any resources being held by the process won't be cleaned up.

Try using a kill SIGTERM (-15) first and then check for the presence of the process still by doing a kill -0 $(cat pid). If it is still hanging around, then by all means clobber it with -9.

SIGTERM can be caught by a process and any process that has been properly written should have a signal handler to catch the SIGTERM and then clean up its resources before exiting.

Comment: Note that you can pass `kill -s TERM` rather than `kill -15`.